# Strongly typing props of vue components using composition api and typescript typing system

Tags: typescript, vue.js, strong-typing, vue-composition-api

I am using vue composition api with typescript.

How can I strongly type the component props using typescript typing system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the official [docs](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html#definecomponent) you can type props in two ways:

Define arops via argument annotation

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent((props: { foo: string }) => {
  props.foo
})
```

Or like this

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    foo: String
  },
  setup(props) {
    props.foo // <- type: string
  }
})
```

Answer (score 62):

Troy Kessier's answer is not entirely accurate. I quote [the documentation on `definecomponent`](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html#definecomponent):

> Alternatively if your component does not use any option other than setup itself, you can pass the function directly […]

So there are not two ways of declaring properties, but rather two ways of declaring a component, and each of them provides its own way of typing props.

With the classic way and TypeScript, use `PropType`:

```
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    someOptionalString: String,

    someRequiredString: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },

    someObject: {
      type: Object as PropType<MyObjectType>,
      required: true
    },
  },

  // …
})
```

*Notice: `PropType` helps to give a correct TypeScript type to the `props` parameter in the `setup` function. But the underlying Vue type for the props remains `Object` and there is currently no way to enforce a better typing for these props passed by the parent component.*

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me, if I pass in { foo: 'bar' } it doesn't complain, in other words it's only checking if the parent component is passing an object, not if it matches the data structure of my custom type. I'm using lang="ts" in the .vue script tag, and TypeScript is working properly in .ts files, and I've got types working nicely in Vuex.

Comment: @LeeComstock Of course. I edited. Let me know if it's clear now.

Comment: Those are not Typescript typings.

Comment: > there is no way to enforce better typing for these props  

— I think there is. You can define a schema using zod and add a validator for every prop. Just make a utility function and it’ll be rather straight-forward to use. This doesn’t enforce it at compile-time, but that’s unfortunately a fundamental limit of vue’s non-standard "amazing" template syntax...

Comment: Also, please note that when using vue2 + `@vue/composition-api`, the `PropType` should instead be imported from that package, not from `vue` itself. Otherwise, at least for me, it’ll error everywhere.