# how to compile time check strongly typed props in vue templates?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Using Vue with Typescript makes it possible to specify  types for props: [Strongly typing props of vue components using composition api and typescript typing system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966387/strongly-typing-props-of-vue-components-using-composition-api-and-typescript-typ)

However, as far as I can see these props are only checked at runtime. Here's a simple example component. It has two props `a`, and `b`. One is a number and the other a string. Additionally `b` has a validator, it is only valid if it's equal to `hi`

```
<template>
  <p>{{a}}</p>
</template>

<script>
import {defineComponent} from 'vue';
export default defineComponent(
    {
        name: "TestComp",
        props:{
            a:number,
            b:{
                type: String,
                validator:(val)=>val=="hi"
            }
        }
    }
)
</script>
```

Here's how you could (incorrectly) use the component. The prop `a` has a wrong type and the prop `b` fails its validation:

```
<TestComp a="hi" b="ho"/>
```

Is it possible to find this bug at compile time?
Out of the box, Vue only complains at runtime, with a message such as `Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "b".`

After searching online, I found that prop type validation can be switched on as an experimental [Vetur feature](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/interpolation.html#prop-type-validation). But this doesn't call the custom validator, so in the example above, Vetur can't find the problem for `b`.
Also, I'm not always using Vetur and would prefer to have the wrong types trigger an actual compile time error.

Comment: `validator` can be **anything** so I'm pretty sure this is not something you can check at compile time...

Comment: You'd have to execute it, but I don't see why that shouldn't be possible. In any case, I would be happy with only checking the types, without running the validator on top of it.

Comment: ^^ just to be clear: checking the types with __Vue__ and at __compile time__, not with the Vetur extension.

Answer (score 1):

For (a): Type definitions

The Typescript / Vue Template compiler does not check for this.

Why? Because the type information is not available to the template compiler.

It is possible to analyze this outside the "normal" template compiler. WebStorm has a check for this.

For (b): Validator

The validation is done at runtime and cannot be checked at compile time.

You can write many of those assertions by [adding the exact type to the prop](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props), then WebStorm can check them. When using type checks, it is best use typescript (although you can use /** @type */ comments, too)

```
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from 'vue';
export default defineComponent(
    {
        name: "TestComp",
        props:{
            b:{
                type: String as PropType<"hi">,
                validator:(val)=>val==="hi"
            }
        }
    }
)
</script>
```

Comment: *then WebStorm can check them* - is this really known? It provides hints regarding prop types in templates but doesn't have any kind of indication that wrong type was provided.

Comment: Yes, it did for some time but probably had too many problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [vue-tsc](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/tree/master/vue-language-tools/vue-tsc). It's a part of [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) `vue-ts` preset that allows to check Vue templates on compile. I was going to use Vite along with Webpack just for templates type checking, but it seems like vue-tsc can do it by itself. However Vite CLI makes configuration easier as it provides all the base TS config, so we only need to compare with already existed tsconfig and take what we need.